# How can i prevent duplicate rows being selected in a select query?

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I have been given the task of selecting key data from an Oracle database, but I am noticing that my select is returning duplicate rows. I don't need them for my report yet I don't want them to delete them. Could someone help to get only the data that I need. I have tried the following code but this doesn't help.

```
SELECT distinct bbp.SUBCAR "Treadwell",
       bbp.BATCH_ID "Batch ID",
       bcs.SILICON "Si",
       bcs.SULPHUR "S",
       bcs.MANGANESE "Mn",
       bcs.PHOSPHORUS "P",
       to_char(bcs.SAMPLE_TIME, 'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') "Sample Time",
       to_char(bbp.START_POUR, 'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') "Start Pour Time",
       to_char(bbp.END_POUR, 'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') "End pour Time",
       bofcs.temperature "Temperature"
FROM  bof_chem_sample bcs, bof_batch_pour bbp, bof_celox_sample bofcs
WHERE bcs.SAMPLE_CODE= to_char('D1')
AND bbp.BATCH_ID=bcs.BATCH_ID
AND bcs.SAMPLE_TIME>=to_date('01-jan-10')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the query translated to SQL Server type SQL you will see that there is no relation between your **bofcs** table and the rest of your data. Basically it is returning every record in the bofcs' temperature field, and that may be producing duplicate results?.

```
SELECT
     bbp.SUBCAR "Treadwell", 
     bbp.BATCH_ID "Batch ID", 
     bcs.SILICON "Si", 
     bcs.SULPHUR "S",
     bcs.MANGANESE "Mn", 
     bcs.PHOSPHORUS "P", 
     to_char(bcs.SAMPLE_TIME,'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') "Sample Time", 
     to_char(bbp.START_POUR, 'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') "Start Pour Time",
     to_char(bbp.END_POUR, 'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') "End pour Time", 
     bofcs.temperature "Temperature"
FROM 
     bof_chem_sample bcs, 
INNER JOIN 
     bof_batch_pour bbp,
ON
     bbp.BATCH_ID=bcs.BATCH_ID
INNER JOIN
     bof_celox_sample bofcs
ON
     **-- NO RELATION B/N BOFCS and the other tables????**
WHERE 
     bcs.SAMPLE_CODE= to_char('D1') AND 
     bcs.SAMPLE_TIME>=to_date('01-jan-10')
```

Comment: Good catch, I never spotted that. That's a full cartesian join, no wonder there is lots of duplication :)

Comment: Thanks that was a big step in the right direction. I noticed some other disconnects with the the database itself because of that.

Comment: Seeing `distinct` in a query should probably ring alarm bells. It is usually the cover up some problem in the query or in the DB design.

Comment: How do i look at a query translated to SQL Server type SQL?

Answer (score 6):

If your SELECT statement has a DISTINCT in it, then all of the returned records have a unique combination of values across the columns you are selecting. You need to identify which columns return different values across the records you deem to be duplicated.